# Nodejs - encode to base64 with 'private key' and be able to decode only in server

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, cryptojs

My use case is as follows:

1. Incoming http request to server to login
2. User token is generated. The token is a Json object build from various fields. Then convert to String and Base64.

   ```
   const stringObject = {
     elementA: stringA,
     elementB: stringB
   };

   const bufferString = new Buffer(`${JSON.stringify(stringObject)}`);
   const encodedAccessToken = bufferString.toString('base64');
   ```

The generated string can now be decoded anywhere.
Is there a way I can encode it in such as way that only my server will be able to decode it? Like encoding it with some sort of a key.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need encryption. Look for encryption algorithms, such as AES. You will also need to ensure integrity with some sort of HMAC, because "raw" encrypted data can still be changed without knowing the key. Although you may still need to use base64 to serve encrypted data as a string, the encryption algorithm will not have anything to do with base64 by itself.

Comment: Actually what you need is asymmetrical cryptography.

Comment: @JefreySobreiraSantos, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JWT token Node Module : [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

**Encode data and generate token** :

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');
```

> { foo: 'bar' } is your feilds that you encrypt

**Decode by same key `shhhhh`**

```
// verify a token symmetric
jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
  console.log(decoded.foo) // bar
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question, but I think your overall approach is wrong. What you are trying to achieve is to have session data. You don't need to send this data to the client and back. That is not a very good practice. Instead you should store this data on the server, preferably in a database.

What you would do is to create a unique key, something randomly generated. You would store the user data using this key, and send the key to the client to be used on requests. You do it by setting it as a cookie variable as well.

The user data can have additional fields variables for more secure access. Like the IP of the client, and possibly a expiry time for cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

use jsonwebtoken instead. it can encrypt your object with a secret phrase. library like `node-jsonwebtoken` is very easy to use.